# High Sierra phantom Jiggling

Tags: high-sierra

I have a 2017 MacBook Pro running High Sierra 10.13.6.

I have noticed some phantom behavior and am curious if anyone knows what is causing it. It usually occurs when I am typing, either an email, some text or some code. Suddenly I can no longer type (as if my Mac has changed to another program) and all the icons on my Dock sort of vibrate and jiggle around. After a few seconds this stops and I can click on the program I was using and I can continue. If I try to continue my program while it is doing its phantom thing, it just goes back go the phantom behavior. It looks as if it reverts to the Finder instead of the program I was using.

I plan on upgrading the OS soon anyway, but was curious if anyone else has noticed this. It happens at least once a day.

Comment: It would help if you can share a brief motion picture depicting the behavior.

Comment: Agreed, although capturing the behavior is difficult as it occurs infrequently, is brief and prevents me from using any software at the time. A colleague of mine has also observed this so it is possible could be due to the company setup/software if it is not a more widely observed phenomenon

Comment: If you use Launchpad then press-and-hold on any icon, it will jiggle the icons to let you either remove icons or re-arrange them (much like an iOS device).  I have never witnessed this behavior on the dock icons.  Do you have any add-ons that modify desktop behavior installed?  In a (possibly) related note ... I have seen swelling batteries on older macs which can interrupt normal operation of some keys and/or  trackpad usage.

Comment: @TimCampbell This is a very different sort of jiggling. It's not the obvious jiggling you describe but rather a rather disconcerting jiggling of all the icons on my dock. they all jiggle and get pushed to the left as if it is trying to fit an extra icon on to the dock. After a few seconds it goes back to normal. It's just a bit frustrating because I'll be typing something and then realize its not writing any of my text because the dock is busy doing a dance